# foreach repeat the value while insert into array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

let see i have multiple post in array. i want to get all values form array and insert into into database.

when i did `Print_r($posts); its` give all bunch of std obj array so.i think problem in looping because when i do `foreach` with echo every thing comes perfect.

```
    $posts = $topic->curatedPosts; 
    $x = count($posts); // output 20 post this is perfect

    foreach($posts as $post){
    // if i add echo $ title & $content its works its shows me different post.  
        $title = $post->title;
        $content = $post->htmlContent;

        // Create post object
/* but when i try to add in array and save all post in database so everytime only one post return many times. */
        $my_post = array(
            'post_title'    => $title,
            'post_content'  => $content,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_author'   => 1,
            'tax_input'     => array('category'),
            'post_category' => array(744)
        );

        // Insert the post into the database
        wp_insert_post($my_post); 
    }
```

i also tried with this but same result
[Post added same](http://www.myluso.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Posts-%E2%80%B9-MyLuso.com-%E2%80%94-WordPress-2014-07-19-21-08-51.png)
`

```
$x = count($posts);
$y = 0;

while($y <= $x){

 foreach($posts as $post){
  $title = $post->title;
  $content = $post->htmlContent;

  // Create post object
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => $title,
  'post_content'  => $content,
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'tax_input' => array('category'),
  'post_category' => array(744)
);

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post($my_post);

}
$y++;
}
```

`

[Print_r($posts)](http://www.myluso.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/1stWD-Slider.png)

Help me please guyes i really need your help time is running out

its doesn't work on plugin but when i add all code in custom template its works..any expert know what i did wrong.

Comment: I didn't understand you problem too. "but when i try to insert i get the post with same name", explain it better...

Comment: Do you mean `$title` has the same value each loop?

Comment: yes every time insert same value..

Comment: can you print $posts array? We need to check is it right or problem in that array?

Comment: when i did Print_r($posts); its give all bunch of std obj array so.i think problem in looping because when i do foreach with echo every thing comes perfect.

Comment: Try to print $post using print_r(). see if the values are all the same

Comment: Your logic seems correct. try to print `$my_posts` and see the contents.

Comment: what i got after print_r($posts);

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [scoopShortUrl] => http://sco.lt/8TgAbp [imageUrl] => http://img.scoop.it/uxT1nz8Pln2TAkBVeJdE-zl72eJkfbmt4t8yenImKBVVEcIaUH86nQbDznP1hDx3 [pageClicks] => 0 [reactionsCount] => 0 [commentsCount] => 0 [htmlContent] =>

    UNAC Signs Agreement With Portuguese Collective Management Entities AllAfrica.com Luanda — The National Union of Artists and Composers (UNAC) has signed in Luanda some agreements with Portuguese collective management entities, aimed at promoting...

Comment: yes Kyle i see the content title with foreach loop but i dont figure out how i will loop add multiple rows or post in database

Comment: `$id = wp_insert_post($post, $error);` try this and show us the dump of $error after each loop

Comment: i get this error " Undefined variable: error in /home/content/94/11757494/html/wp-content/plugins/1wd-slider/1wd_slider.php on line 111"